# Need help converting a TSQL query to EF using Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Here's the query:

```
select FC.Title, COUNT(FSC.ID) as FCCount, COUNT(FP.NoOfSub), MAX(FP.LastPost)
from ForumCategories FC
left join ForumSubCategories FSC on FSC.CategoryID_FK = FC.ID
left join (select SubCategoryID_FK, Count(ID) NoOfSub, MAX(DatePosted) LastPost  
           from ForumPosts group by SubCategoryID_FK) FP 
on FP.SubCategoryID_FK =  FSC.ID
group by FC.Title
order by FC.Title
```

Comment: If your previous question got closed, it is not a good idea to repost it. Also, just by going off your recent activity, you should at least make some attempt at solving your own problem instead of asking for someone to do it for you on SO. Post what you've tried, what errors you get, etc. Then at least you can be taught what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Agree.  You need to learn the technology, not just post a query and ask for it to get converted.

Comment: LINQ stands for Language Integrated Query, so you have to specify what programming language you want it integrated in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQPad, which does support ADO.NET ENtity framework: http://www.linqpad.net/

Enter in the QUERY, and there is a SQL tab, which is the SQL translation.